# JavaScript showing wrong result for logical Operation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, logical-operators

I have a chrome extension. Its code has a method `getSelectionFromPage()` which catches the text selected on the webpage and always `returns true` like below:

```
function getSelectionFromPage() {
  window.selected = true;
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
  code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
 }, function(selection) {
  if (selection[0] != '') {
    window.selected = true;
  }else{
    window.selected = false;
  }
 });
 return true
}
```

On the same window context, I ran the following commands on the console.
The result can be seen as follows:

[image: console output]

I am writing the same commands here also:

```
getSelectionFromPage() //-> true
window.selected //-> false
(getSelectionFromPage() && window.selected) //-> true
```

The `(getSelectionFromPage() && window.selected)` should be `false`. I have tried checking `typeof(window.selected)` and `typeof(getSelectionFromPage())` and both are returning `boolean`. I don't understand why it is happening.

Comment: True false are part of Boolean data type, I don't see anything wrong with it... Also you used and (&&) operator which `true && false -> false`, aren't you mistaking or (||) operator? `true || false -> true`

Comment: `true && false` should be `false` not `true`.  but && operation showing true. That is my concern too..

Comment: You set windows . Selected=true;, you could check window.selected first ... Java script is not multi-thread or something, when it run a block of code it do it till the end , and and other code which may reset those state won't interfere

Comment: The body of the anonymous function could be written much more concisely as an arrow function: `selection => window.selected == selection[0] != ''`, though you might want `!==` in this case. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function which is setting to false is a callback.  This will not execute until after the current execution context is complete.  Therefore, it will not be set to false until after `&& window.selection` completes execution.

executeScript docs: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript

The order of things is:

```js
(function () {
  window.selected = true; // Runs
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: "window.getSelection().toString();"}, function(){
    window.selected = false;
  }); // Calls browser API and  set's callback (the anonymous function there) to call later)
  // NOTE: the callback function which was set here was NOT executed yet it was only defined.
  return true;
})() // true
&& window.selected // this is currently true
// Later, now callback executes
```

If you would like to wait, you could use a `Promise` instead.

```js
  function getSelectionFromPage() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(
        {code: "window.getSelection().toString();"},
        // or just put resolve here instead of defining a function to get value directly
        function(v){
          resolve(!!v);
        }
      );
    });
  }

  getSelectionFromPage().then(haveSelection => console.log(haveSelection);
```

Comment: The callback function has not executed yet.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I understood that i messed it with asynchronous call.